# Loading Data from Firebase into Recycleview using Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Can anyone help me with this firebase recycler view using fragments issue? I am having a problem with retrieving the data from firebase to my recycler view. I am using fragments and the app crashes everytime I run it.

Here's my code:

SubjecList.java

```
package com.google.myeclassrecordapp.mye_classrecord;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;


public class SubjectsList extends Fragment {


    private View view;
    private Context c;
    private RecyclerView myTimeline;
    private FirebaseDatabase databaseReference;
    private DatabaseReference mFireDatabasaeRef;
    private LinearLayoutManager mananger;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ScheduleListAdapter, ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.schedule_model, container, false);

        mFireDatabasaeRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("SubjectsList");
        c = getContext();

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rcsched);
        mananger = new LinearLayoutManager(c);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ScheduleListAdapter, ViewHolder>(
                ScheduleListAdapter.class,
                R.layout.schedule_model,
                ViewHolder.class,
                mFireDatabasaeRef
                )
                {

            @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, ScheduleListAdapter model, int position) {


                            viewHolder.setSubjectCode(model.getSubjectCode());
                            viewHolder.setSection(model.getSection());
                            viewHolder.setTime(model.getTime());
                            viewHolder.setDay(model.getDay());
                            viewHolder.setRoom(model.getRoom());


                    }
                };





       mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mananger);

        return view;


    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;



        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }


            public void setSubjectCode(String subjectcode){

            TextView txtSubjectCode = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtsubjectcode);
            txtSubjectCode.setText(subjectcode);

              }

        public void setSection(String section){

            TextView txtSection = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtsection);
            txtSection.setText(section);

        }
        public void setTime(String time){

            TextView txtTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txttime);
            txtTime.setText(time);

        }
        public void setDay(String day){

            TextView txtDay = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtday);
            txtDay.setText(day);

        }

        public void setRoom(String room){

            TextView txtRoom = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtroom);
            txtRoom.setText(room);

        }


        }
    }



ScheduleListAdapater.java

package com.google.myeclassrecordapp.mye_classrecord;

/**
 * Created by Pau-Le on 5/12/17.
 */

public class ScheduleListAdapter {

    private String SubjectCode;
    private String Section;
    private String Time;
    private String Day;
    private String Room;


    public ScheduleListAdapter() {


    }

    public ScheduleListAdapter(String subjectCode, String section, String time, String day, String room) {
        SubjectCode = subjectCode;
        Section = section;
        Time = time;
        Day = day;
        Room = room;
    }

    public String getSubjectCode() {
        return SubjectCode;
    }

    public void setSubjectCode(String subjectCode) {
        SubjectCode = subjectCode;
    }

    public String getSection() {
        return Section;
    }

    public void setSection(String section) {
        Section = section;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return Time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        Time = time;
    }

    public String getDay() {
        return Day;
    }

    public void setDay(String day) {
        Day = day;
    }

    public String getRoom() {
        return Room;
    }

    public void setRoom(String room) {
        Room = room;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Atif yeah It is working fine if using activity however if I am using fragments it cause an error and crashing my app

Comment: for fragment instead of activity name use getActivity()

Comment: if u need help in custom adapter I have done work on that .

Comment: Yeah I also used it but my problem isa recycler view adapter having an error if that is okay can you send me the source code pls

Comment: post that error.???